# Что такое литералы?

Tags: терминология, константа, литерал

В следующем примере `1` и `Кот` это литералы, а `a1`, `c` и `cat` — переменные:

```
int a1 = 1;
int c = a1;
string cat = "Кот";
```

Если "Литерал" это фиксированное значение, то зачем это терминология когда есть термин "константа" ?

Answer (score 3):

Потому что в программировании `константа` - это **переменная** с **фиксированнным значением**.

В то же время и само **значение** такой переменной - это в общем-то тоже `константа`.

Видимо, поэтому, чтобы избежать неоднозначности толкования - о чём же мы всё-таки говорим, когда в программировании произносим термин `константа` - ввели термин `литерал`.

Поэтому в программировании обычно понимают так:

- `константа` - это **переменная**, содержащая **фиксированное значение** (нонсенс, если подумать - "переменная" и в то же время "фиксированная", но так сложилось)
- `литерал` - это само **фиксированное значение**, которое присваивается **переменной-константе** или ещё каким-то образом используется в программе (в общем-то не обязательно его куда-то присваивать)

Answer (score 0):

константа и литерал - это разные сущности

константа - это данные, которые нельзя изменять

а литералы - это некоторые числовые или цифровые префиксы и суффиксы, которые описывают данные, хранящиеся в переменных и константах

```
const float pi = 3.1415; // pi - константа

const float pi = 3.1415f // f - литерал, показывающий, что число 3.1415 имеет тип float
```

или например в C++11 появились литералы для времени -

```
auto delta = 250ms;
```

`ms` - это литерал

т.е. когда вы используете `const` - вы говорите компилятору, что значение данной переменной не может быть изменено напрямую (обходы есть, но сейчас не об этом)

а когда вы используете литералы, то вы говорите компилятору как именно интерпретировать данные, которые вы записываете в переменную

Comment: В Википедии, откуда автор вопроса взял пример, считают немного иначе :)  Можно было бы подумать, что в русской Вики опять какой-то косяк, но нет: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)

Comment: @CrazyElf, википедия - да, это я про литеральные суффиксы все таки:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal, а сами литералы к примеру - https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/literals/